# How can I sort DataTable Column which is containing Decimal value with $ sign - JQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

Hello I want to sort the columns which is having values as follows:

```
$6.99
$6.49
$10.31
$1.75
$1.02
```

Now when I do sorting, it considers $6.99 as the highest, when $10.31 is bigger than $6.99. I visited some stack questions and found this solution

```
"language": {
                "decimal": ".",
            }
```

But it is not working as well. Please help me out with this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `num-fmt` for the type of the column either in the `columnDefs` or a `columns` array options:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "type": "num-fmt", 
        "targets": X // X = the index of your currency column
    }]
});
```

Comment: I have tried, everything else is getting sorted perfectly but $10.31 should come first it's not coming on top

Comment: Perhaps a minimal JSFiddle would help with debugging your use case? You did remember that the index is 0 based?

Comment: Thank you for your help friend, I know this should have worked, but don't know why it's not working in my case. I have used another library now for sorting and it's working perfectly. I highly appreciate your help. Thanks once again